# Remove unwanted character from WMIC output using Java replace()

Tags: java, string, unicode, replace, wmic

I am currently working on a system configuration checker. For this purpose, I need to retrieve the Operating System of the tested machine and test it against a `.csv` file.

Unfortunately, while testing, one machine gave me quite the headache : upon retrieving the string from the WMI command, a `ÿ` character is inserted where a space should be. As a result, my string comparison is wrong when in fact it shouldn't. Here is a small code block to help you understand the process :

```
    //The command to execute
    String masterCommand = "wmic os get ";
    String command = "Caption";

    //The process that executes the command
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", masterCommand + command);
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    //The command result stored in a string
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
    //The string cleaned of unwanted substring and trailing spaces
    result = result.replace(command, "").trim();
```

The expected result would be `Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise` but it ends up being `Microsoft Windowsÿ10 Enterprise`

I thought that using Java's `replace()` method would solve the problem but it does nothing. Here is the replace I am currently using.

```
    result = result.replace("(?i)windows.", "Windows ");
```

I should add that the command (`wmic os get Caption`) outputs the correct result on the cmd and also seems to output it correctly to a `.txt` file.

---

**TL;DR**

I use a wmic inside Java using `ProcessBuilder` and get an unwanted character (`ÿ`) that isn't detected by `replace()`.

**What could I do to get the correct result (avoiding writing to a file and then reading it) ?**

---

Please, point out any need for clarification or rectification.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is kinda clunky but works for me.

Because the unwanted character is a Unicode character, I simply clean the string by keeping ASCII only characters.

```
result = result.replaceAll("[^ -~]", "").trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
result = result.replace("(?i)windows[^ ]", "Windows ");
```

What this does is it takes the `result` String and replaces by nothing (`""` empty string) all character whose value is outside the  (white space) to `~` range ([printable ASCII](http://www.catonmat.net/images/favorite-regex/ascii-table.png)).

The additional code simply trims all spaces and replaces 2+ spaces by a single one.
The last line takes care of potential printable ASCII characters coming between "Windows" and its version (e.g. 7, XP, Vista, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
     String result = "Microsoft Windowsÿ10 Enterprise";
     result = result.replace('ÿ', ' ');
     System.out.println(result); //prints Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
```

Comment: Sorry for this late answer.
I already tried what you suggest but unfortunately, it didn't work.